# Give a general formula in terms of $n$ for the determinant of the following matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $M_n$ denote the $n$ x $n$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ of which the entry in the $i$-th row and the $j$-th column equals $1$ if $|i-j|\leq 1$ and $0$ otherwise. For example:
$M_6=$
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
1& 1& 1& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 1& 1& 1& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 1& 1& 1& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 1& 1& 1\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 1
\end{pmatrix}
Give (with proof) a general formula in terms of $n$ for the determinant of $M_n$.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I can calculate the determinant when i get a concrete $n$ (like $n=6$), but I can't find a general formula and I certainly can't prove it.

Comment: @RobertMulen The author of the problem probably intended the solver to see that after expanding $\text{det } M_n$ using known techniques (Laplace expansion, row reduction, etc), the result involves matrices of the form $M_k$ with $k < n$. This leads to a recurrence relation, which can be used to find a general formula and give a proof of that formula. This is not a strategy that works for all determinant evaluation problems, but it's one tool in the toolbox.

Answer (score 3):

solve the recurrence relations $D_n = D_{n-1} - D_{n-2}$ with the initial condition $D_1 = 1 \mbox{ and} D_2 = 0.$ try $D_n = \lambda^n.$ the indicial equation is $\lambda^2 - \lambda + 1 = 0$ whose roots are $\lambda = {1 \pm i\sqrt 3 \over 2}.$ sso $D_n = k (\cos(n\pi/3 + \phi).$ requiring $D_2 = 0$ gives $\phi = -\pi/6$ and $D_! = 1$ shows $k = \frac{2}{\sqrt 3}.$

so the answer is $$D_n = \frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\cos(n\pi/3 - \pi/6).$$

i hope i did not make too many errors.

Comment: I suspect, though I haven't checked, that your calculation is correct. However, doesn't the sequence consist of 1's, 0's, and -1's determined by the value of $n \pmod 6$? (i.e., isn't there a more pleasing form for the answer?)

Comment: @Hugh Denoncourt, you mean i did all that work and now you tell me it is just the periodic sequence $1,0,-1,-1,0,1,\cdots?$ thanks for noticing the periodicity.